# Android: Switch activities across menu

Tags: android

I have three Activity with menu. Across menu can switch activities. I took the 'android:launchMode="singleInstance' to AndroidManifest for I remain the modifications on each Activity.

```
 ------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|        A         |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
|##A##|  B  |  C   |
 ------------------
      A Activity

 ------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|        B         |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
|  A  |##B##|  C   |
 ------------------
      B Activity

 ------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|        C         |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
|  A  |  B  |##C## |
 ------------------
      C Activity
```

This is work correctly. My problem is that, when I push a back key because I want to exit, I have to push three times for to close the app.
I want eliminate this procedure. So when I on A, B or C Activity, and I push back key, close them all. Somehow I want jump back stack.
I try use Activity Flags. For example like this:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, B.class);
    intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
```

With this I have two problems. It just supported API 11 or upper, and this not close the other Activity. (when I launch again, I see the other activities modifications is remained)
I know **Fragment**s, and it would be a lot easier with these, but I have to need solved without **Fragment**s.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I would really recommend you to use Fragments, there won't be any problem at all if you use them.

Answer (score 0):

You already know It is much easier with Fragments and it is recommended to use Fragments But if you want to do it this way... before every new activity you start call finish();

like

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

It will finish the Activity A and start activity B. This way if you press back in Activity B your application will close.

Comment: yeah, but I lost modifications when I'm switching Activities

Comment: if I call finish, the activity will be closed, and reset the state. I lose data e.g. from EditText which user filled. There will be complex controllers, so I don't want save at all.

Comment: I would suggest you use Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is an old style programming with tabs holding activities.

Here an example http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

If you do not want the tabs to be visible its easy to hide them completely.

But personally I would suggest fragments.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a custom `Back` activity stack:

```
// Creates an explicit intent for the top activity that will be opened (the map)
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, <your_activity>.class);
resultIntent.putExtras(extras);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity. This ensures that navigating backward from the 
// Activity leads out of your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(<your_activity>.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
stackBuilder.startActivities();
```

What that code essentially is doing, is that the activity from pressing back and the next activity, are the same. This way, when back is pressed, you will exist to the Home screen.

Comment: It is a Honeycomb feature, but I have just noticed its part of Support Library. I'm checking.